# What is this notation in the movie Hidden Figures?

Tags: notation

I just finished watching the movie "Hidden Figures" and noticed this rather odd notation on the chalkboard:

[image: inline screenshot]

What does it mean?

Comment: Looks like $\frac{2\pi t}{\tau}$, which is standard lettering in mathematics.

Answer (score 3):

$\tfrac{2\pi t}{\tau}$.

Since the movie is about orbital mechanics, I guess this refers to the angle of something in a circular orbit at time $t$, having an orbital period $\tau$.